# ASP.NET Devexpress controls don't show correctly on live server

Tags: asp.net, iis, devexpress, iis-7.5

On Visual Studio.NET 2010/localhost, an ASP.NET page developed with Devexpress editor and textbox controls looks nice. When uploaded to IIS 7.5, the generated html source is almost identical, except for the references to script WebResources (script src="/WebResource.axd?d=tpzArdJXo7erNNqm...), but the validators don't fire and the controls have a different style.

Somewhere on the DevExpress website I read that WebResources may become inaccessible for some reason and that one should stop the IIS service, clear the Temporary ASP.NET files and the GAC cache, and restart. Restarting the IIS is out of question, and I refuse to believe that this is the only solution.

Any suggestions?

I'm using DevExpress version 10.1.7.0. This is the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
        <configSections>
            <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                        <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                        <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                        <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                        <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    </sectionGroup>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </configSections>
        <appSettings>
            <!-- Use semi-colons to separate entries-->
            <add key="ExcludeFromErrorMails" value="Der Thread wurde abgebrochen;Datei ist nicht vorhanden;This is an invalid webresource request'"/>
            <add key="CuteWebUI.AjaxUploader.UseAspNetStream" value="True"/>
        </appSettings>
        <connectionStrings>
    ...
     </connectionStrings>
        <system.web>
            <urlMappings enabled="true">
                <add url="~/QAAwards.aspx" mappedUrl="~/FAQ/QAAwards.aspx"/>
            </urlMappings>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>
            <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1800" maxRequestLength="50000"/>
            <compilation debug="true">
                <assemblies>
                    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor.v10.1, Version=10.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v10.1, Version=10.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v10.1, Version=10.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpellChecker.v10.1, Version=10.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                    <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v10.1, Version=10.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                    <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraSpellChecker.v10.1.Core, Version=10.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/></assemblies>
            </compilation>
            <authentication mode="Windows"/>
            <pages>
                <controls>
                    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                    <add namespace="CuteWebUI" assembly="CuteWebUI.AjaxUploader" tagPrefix="CuteWebUI"/>
                    <add namespace="MagicAjax.UI.Controls" assembly="MagicAjax" tagPrefix="MagicAjax"/>
                </controls>
            </pages>
            <httpHandlers>
                <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
                <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
            </httpHandlers>
            <httpModules>
                <add name="MagicAjax" type="MagicAjax.MagicAjaxModule, MagicAjax"/>
                <add name="CuteWebUI.UploadModule" type="CuteWebUI.UploadModule,CuteWebUI.AjaxUploader"/>
                <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </httpModules>
        </system.web>
        <system.codedom>
            <compilers>
                <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
                </compiler>
                <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                    <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
                    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
                </compiler>
            </compilers>
        </system.codedom>
        <system.webServer>
            <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
            <modules>
                <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
                <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </modules>
            <handlers>
                <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
                <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
                <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
                <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
                <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
        <runtime>
            <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
                <dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
                </dependentAssembly>
                <dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
                </dependentAssembly>
            </assemblyBinding>
        </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open Handler Mappings property in the IIS settings of the web application's and make certain that

AssemblyResourceLoader-Integrated and AssemblyResourceLoader-Integrated 4.0 has the request path equal to WebResource.axd 
and 
Type is System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.

Also, please make certain that the Pipeline mode of the application's Pool is set to the Integrated mode.

Olaf, your web.config file does not contain registration information about our [http handler](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument6769).  To register ASPxHttpHandlerModule and enable its features, just place a DevExpress web control on the form or add specific code to the web.config file manually. For more information, see the [How to manually register a HttpHandler Module](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/K18262.aspx) topic.

Comment: Thanks, but all settings are exactly as you describe. They are the default settings which we have not touched.

Comment: Due to some reason, the standard web resource handler does not work on your machine.  Please tell us which version of our controls you are using.  Also, post your web.config file here.

Comment: Thanks for the great support! Good to know that DevExpress is handling issues. 
The version number as well as the web.config are edited into the question as they don't fit into the comment.

Comment: Olaf, I edited the original answer with a new information.  It should help you.

Comment: That's it!!! Thank you so much. Again, great support.

The ASPxHttpHandlerModule type in the modules section was missing. So simple once you know where to look. Works very well now.